# Photo Gallery fails to open pictures

Tags: windows, permissions, windows-vista, pictures

I have a friend who is having some trouble with their computer so they called me over to help out.

The issue is that when I try to open a picture, then MS Photo Gallery fails to display it and displays the following error message:  "Photo Gallery can't open this picture because you do not have permissions to access the file location"

I tried editing the picture and it does display it in Paint, but I can't actually save any pictures that I open or create in paint. The error there was:

```
Paint cannot save this file.
Save was interrupted, so your file has not been saved.
```

I [checked for possible solutions on Microsoft](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-pictures/photo-gallery-tells-me-that-i-dont-have-the/1ec4c84f-ae6f-456d-a54f-ce74a848d303), but I couldn't apply it this case because I can't save the file. The suggested workaround would be a horrible way to do it anyway, I'd have to edit ALL of my friend's pictures just to get this "workaround" to "work."

Any ideas on what may be wrong here?

OS: Windows Vista Home Premium

Comment: How is this possibly a serverfault question? Please read the FAQ.

Comment: What's a better place for this question in the stackexchange world?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to run a disk check on the disk where you're having problems. It is very likely a corrupted index that is causing your problem.

Comment: I did that, but didn't find any problems... for now I told my friend to back up everything. I'll go back later this week and I'll run another check, but most likely I'll just reinstall Vista. Nuke FTW!

Comment: Did you run it with "Check for bad sectors" enabled?

Comment: Pretty sure I did... but it's my friend's PC and I don't have the computer in front of my anymore so I can't run the test again.